# When a servlet output java script (page show one string), how to use "curl " (or java code) to visit this servlet to get same result?

Tags: javascript, java, curl, servlets

I am a java newbie and met this question, anyone can help would be appreciate ;)
   Actually, I write a java servlet, and this servlet, just output javascript code to generate a virtual html page, and in this html's JS code will output a 'String' I need (acutally decrypted RSA psd). this works fine when use browser, but when I used 'curl' command (java code also) to visit this servlet, it returns just the whole JS code ,not the 'String' I needed.
   I tried set "contentType text/html", "application/json"  etc, but always return  JS code.  Is the method wrong? how can I get the String at backend?

some code like this:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jsencrypt.js\"></script> ");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body onload=testenc()>");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("<script>");
out.println(" function testenc() ");
out.println("{");
out.println(" var encrypts = new JSEncrypt();");
out.println("encrypts.setPublicKey('MIGfMA0GCSqG.....
```

---

The browser just display like:
MGFuXPaCe+NgHUYQh8Xq86ooG13RJaxwyX2ZxIxhm+ewi/rrQPKbnz0hugwxdWcy3wBLuTx5bxougDLU0Bo... 
But curl command will return whole source code?
any help would be thanks.

Comment: curl doesn't run HTML/JavaScript. Web browsers run HTML/JavaScript. You need to reframe your question.

Comment: OK, got it , thanks.   So if don't consider 'curl', Can I use java code to visit this servlet and get 'String'?

Comment: No idea. Carefully read through http://xyproblem.info and reframe your question. It's unclear why exactly you're doing this all in a seemingly overcomplicated way. I have a strong impression that you ultimately don't need a servlet or a HTML page at all. Most probably even no JavaScript.

Comment: OK, let me explain. what I want is to  decrypt a rsa encrypted string in  java backend. this   is used in CAS sso envirement, user's psd is encrypted by jsencrpt.js and send to java backend. in backend,I can this string and need to decrypt. I  just want to try use servlet to  invoke jsencrpt.js 's decrypt method to  do it . and in SSO, only servlet can be visit, other jsp or html will be block. so I want to  do it in server sid, use Java engine to simulate client brower to run js and get string deencrypted, is it possiable? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use JavaScript `jsencrypt.js` instead of Java `javax.crypto.Cipher` for this?